# error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, macos, casting

I have a code that uses KVO functionality.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    ...
    let oldRect = change?[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] as! NSRect
```

So when I am trying to cast value to NSRect I am getting the error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

And the object is NSRect type object:

```
(lldb) po change?[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  - Some : NSRect: {{293, 21}, {108, 108}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the `change` parameter of `observeValueForKeyPath(_:ofObject:change:context:)` is of type `[String : AnyObject]?`, and internally, it's an `NSDictionary`, which cannot contain `NSRange` as a value.

So, KVO converts the value to an `NSValue` containing `NSRange`. But unfortunately, it cannot be directly bridged to `NSRange` in Swift.

Try something like this:

```
    let oldRect = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] as! NSValue).rectValue
```